# Kill child process only after readFile() Node js Electron

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, electron

I'm using an imported `ffmpeg` binary `ffmpeg-static-electron`in an Electron-React app (on Windows Pro 10) and want to delete a saved cropped video and then kill the child process afterwards from my `Main process`.

The overall aim is to crop a video of the whole screen following capture and then send the cropped video to a renderer.

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static-electron')
const { execFile } = require("child_process")


ipcMain.on("windoze_capture_screen:video_buffer", async (event, buffer) => {
    const temp_directory =  await fsPromises.mkdtemp(await fsPromises.realpath(os.tmpdir()) + path.sep)
    const capture_screen_video_path = path.join(temp_directory, "screen_capture_video.mp4")

    child_object = execFile(`${ffmpeg.path}`, 

            ['-i', `${capture_screen_video_path}`, '-vf', `crop=${width}:${height}:${x_pos}:${y_pos}`, `${path.join(temp_directory,'cropped_video.mp4')}`])
            
    child_object.on("exit", async () => {

        // child_object.kill()
        console.log("?Killed -1", child_object.killed)
        
        try { 
            databasePayload.video_buffer = await fsPromises.readFile(path.join(temp_directory, "cropped_video.mp4"), {encoding: 'base64'})
            mainWindow.webContents.send("main_process:video_buffer", databasePayload.video_buffer)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } finally {

            // child_object.kill()
            console.log("?Killed - 2", child_object.killed)
            
            // noASAR required to be set to 'true' in order to remove temp directory in build
            process.noAsar = true 
            fs.rmdir(temp_directory, {recursive: true}, (error) => {if (error) {log(error)}})
            process.noASAR = false
            }

            // 3rd scenario
            // child_object.kill()
            console.log("?Killed -3", child_object.killed)   
        })

        // 4th scenario
        console.log("?Killed-4", child_object.killed)   
    })
```

When running each of these scenarios, I get the following outputs.

Scenario's 1, 2 and 3 - Successfully sends cropped video to renderer but doesn't kill process.

Output:

```
?Killed-4 false
?Killed -1 false
[ffmpeg version 3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC).... etc. ]
?Killed-2 false
?Killed -3 false
```

Scenario 4 - Doesn't crop video

```
?Killed-4 true
?Killed -1 true
Command failed: C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\windows-electron-forge\node_modules\ffmpeg-static-electron\bin\win\x64\ffmpeg.exe -i C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\4WgnUw\screen_capture_video.mp4 -vf crop=796:763:462:509 C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\4WgnUw\cropped_video.mp4

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\4WgnUw\cropped_video.mp4'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\4WgnUw\\cropped_video.mp4'
}
?Killed - 2 true
?Killed -3 true
```

The last scenario has been tried out of desperation.

Question: Where am I going wrong with this ? I suspect it's something to do with ipc between child and parent process but not sure where to place the code.

Any help will be much appreciated !!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code so that it's actually intelligible. Currently, this is a mess of mixed indentation and misplaced braces -- we can help you more easily and way faster if we can actually comprehend the code at first glance. Also, please split your code and the output you've included (probably by accident) in the very same block. Furthermore, please clarify why `process.noAsar` needs to be set -- it shouldn't, really.

Comment: Apologies - still learning how to code. I hope this is a little clearer. 'process.noAsar' is necessary for the build (using Electron-forge). Without including this piece of code, the directory was not being removed during the build.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've received the `exit` event in your `.on ("exit", () => { ... });` function, there is no need to kill the child process -- it has already exited on its own, meaning it has finished running and will "die" because there is nothing left to do. Killing processes is only needed when they should be forced to abort what they are currently doing or if they misbehave and stick around without actually doing anything (which can be observed in the Task Manager of your OS).

As the [Node.js documentation on `exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit) states, this event will only trigger when the process terminates. Thus, you no longer can kill it in the handler function and actually don't need to, because it won't stick around as a so-called "zombie" (see above) as it has already finished execution.

Thus, the following function should be sufficient:

```js
child_object.on("exit", async () => {
    try {
        databasePayload.video_buffer = await fsPromises.readFile(path.join(temp_directory, "cropped_video.mp4"), {encoding: 'base64'})
        mainWindow.webContents.send("main_process:video_buffer", databasePayload.video_buffer)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    
    // ... your file removal code ...
});
```

---

There are three more things I would like to address:

- When requiring promises to actually be resolved before continuing with the code following them, it's better not to use `await` but rather use the function's synchronous version if available. Your `fs` function calls would then become:

```js
const fs = require ("fs");
const temp_directory = fs.mkdtempSync (fs.realpathSync (os.tmpdir()) + path.sep)
// ...
databasePayload.video_buffer = fs.readFileSync (path.join (temp_directory, "cropped_video.mp4"), { encoding: 'base64' })
// ...
try { fs.rmdirSync (temp_directory, { recursive: true }) } catch (e) { console.log (e); }
```

- `process.noAsar = true` should not be needed unless your temporary directory was actually created inside your application's ASAR archive which is unlikely unless Electron Forge does some magic I'm not aware of. Consider investigating why setting this flag solves your problem (probably by dumping the temporary directory's path).
- A temporary directory should not be needed for a single file. Unless you plan to use this directory as a storage space for more files, consider rewriting the function to create a temporary file instead and then delete this single file (this will also be easier on the disk hardware, as only one deletion needs to be performed instead of two, but that is actually negligible unless you do this hundreds of times).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've made changes as suggested. I set up the creation and deletion of the temp file based on this article: [https://advancedweb.hu/secure-tempfiles-in-nodejs-without-dependencies]. Regarding killing the child process, looks like I've assumed that persistence of the process in the build version may be responsible for the fact that the cropping only works on the first occasion when running the .exe build file. I have to close the app and restart it everytime. Checking ```child.isKilled``` returns ```false``` in dev (basis for my assumption that its a zombie process).

Comment: The `killed` property will only be `true` when you have successfully called `kill()` ([source](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_killed)) Regarding "it only works on the first occasion": I suggest you ask a new question, because every time a new `ffmpeg` process should have been created. Try to gather a little more debugging information (is there any output?) for that question, however. If this answer has helped you so far, please remember to upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I refactored my code to run execFile() from the renderer process, hoping it would kill all child processes on closing of the window. Unfortunately, this didn't work and resulted in an entirely different ENOENT error when reading the file path to the recorded screencapture. Can't see a way to get a log when running in build mode. Works as expected in dev. Would upvote but not allowed to with rep < 15  :(

Comment: Let me reiterate this: Once your `.on("exit", ...)` function runs, you can no longer kill the process -- it's *gone* already. (Why do you still want to kill the process? Do you see it sticking around?) I/O operations should, however, be run from the main process. Also, please open a new question for the other problem, as that is not related to this one. Make sure to include the complete path that triggers `ENOENT` in that new question. It could very well be that the path is deleted before you've had a chance to read the file.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My code now executes ```execFile()``` from the renderer process and (as you've indicated), successfully kills the associated ```child process```,  resulting in a saved cropped_video.mp4 file (in a temp_folder). I ended up adding an event listener to the renderer ```BrowserWindow``` in the  ```main``` process to read the cropped video file and convert to a base64 string (as per my requirements) once the window closes. It works if you get the timing right but not ideal. Now I just need an event driven way to read the video file AFTER the file has been created... Thx